# TypeOrm/PostgreSQL createQueryBuilder: select column from joined table

Tags: postgresql, nestjs, typeorm

I want to select only a column from a table that I'm joining into. A `separator` has a `facility`, a `facility` has a `customer`, and I want to select `customer.id` by providing a `separatorId`.

Below is what I have tried, but this returns a `Separator`.

```
return await this.separatorRepository
  .createQueryBuilder('separator')
  .select(['customer.companyId'])
  .innerJoin('separator.facility', 'facility')
  .innerJoin('facility.customer', 'customer')
  .where('separator.id = :separatorId', { separatorId })
  .getOne();
```

How do I change this query to get `customer.id`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose your joined tables are not selected from because you use `innerJoin` method instead of `innerJoinAndSelect`. Additionally, since `getOne` returns objects with your entity type (`Separator` in your case), you need to make sure the relations between `Separator`, `Facility`, and `Customer` are properly specified.

Entities:

```js
@Entity()
export class Customer {
    @PrimaryColumn()
    id: number;
}

@Entity()
export class Facility {
    @PrimaryColumn()
    id: number;

    @OneToOne(() => Customer)
    @JoinColumn()
    customer: Customer;
}

@Entity()
export class Separator {
    @PrimaryColumn()
    id: number;

    @OneToOne(() => Facility)
    @JoinColumn()
    facility: Facility;
}
```

Query:

```js
return await this.separatorRepository
  .createQueryBuilder('separator')
  .innerJoinAndSelect('separator.facility', 'facility')
  .innerJoinAndSelect('facility.customer', 'customer')
  .where('separator.id = :separatorId', { separatorId })
  .getOne();
```

The query yields you the instance of `Separator` with the joined entities, so you could get your `customer.id` from there.